# My soldiers all march to the same spot, how do i give them seperate orders simulanelously?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

In a follow up to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28095/in-a-bge-rts-how-could-i-make-a-selection-box-to-select-units) fantastic question that I've been waiting for some one to ask, I would like to know how I can send d people in an RTS game to different locations. I already have an empty being added with a different property each time I click, but I don't know how to get flocks to only steer toward an object with a certain property, and not just the object.

How can I set an object to only seek empty with property[goto]=1 while anoter group is seeking empty with property[goto]=2, and so forth? This would be really helpful, thanks.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a .blend to start with ?

Comment: Already done. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make every characters go to a certain target whenever you click the ground we create `flag` object and set it as a target for the selected characters,
when all the characters reaches the flag, it gets deleted

---

***Details :***

we have the function `main()` which is excuted when you <kbd>MMB</kbd>click on the ground this function :

- creates a new Flag object at cursor position
- loop through all objects and find the selected ones that have `Move` property, 
  *for each found object :*
- change the `Steering` actuator `target` to this new Flag
- increment the Flag `Followers` property by one
- set the object properties `Active` and `Move` to `True`
- when Active and Move are set the object start seeking the flag

this is done with this part of code :

```
main():
.......
    flag = scene.addObject("Flag", "Tracker", 0)
            for obj in scene.objects :
                if obj.get('Select', False) and 'Move' in obj.getPropertyNames() :
                    obj.actuators["SeekTracker"].target = flag
                    obj['Move'] = True
                    obj['Active'] = True
                    flag['Followers'] +=1
```

The Flag has property `Followers` which indicate how many objects have it as a target, so if it has no followers it should be removed , for this we have a function `flag_self_check()` which does that, the code part for this is :

```
def flag_self_check():

        cont = logic.getCurrentController()
        own = cont.owner

        if own['Followers'] == 0 :
            own.endObject()
```

but what makes the `Followers` count goes down ? it is the object, the moving object has a near sensor to detect the flag when the object gets near the flag it stops Moving and decrement the flag `Followers` count by one

```
def reach_dest():

        cont = logic.getCurrentController()
        own = cont.owner
        sen = cont.sensors["Near"]

        if sen.positive :
            hit_flag = sen.hitObjectList[0] 
            if hit_flag :
                if hit_flag == target :
                    hit_flag['Followers'] -= 1
                    own['Move'] = False
```

---

i have added `if hit_flag == target :` so moving object don't stop at the wrong flag when passing by

[image]